# Model object not refreshed after change made in View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, binding

My controller.js

```
'use strict';
var phoneApp=angular.module("phoneApp",[]);
phoneApp.controller('PhoneListController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.phones=[{name:'NOKIA',model:1010,price:3000},{name:'MOTOROLA',model:5655,price:5000},{name:'SAMSUNG',model:6567,price:8000}];
$scope.noOfPhones=$scope.phones.length;
$scope.addNewPhone=function()
{
    $scope.phones.push({name:$scope.phoneName,model:$scope.phoneModel,price:$scope.phonePrice});
};
});

------------
index.html
------------
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phoneApp" ng-controller="PhoneListController">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{phone.name}} - {{phone.model}} - {{phone.price}}</li>
</ul>
 <p>Total number of phones: {{noOfPhones}}</p>
 <h3>Add New Phone</h3>
 Phone Name :<input type=text ng-model="phoneName"/>
 Phone Model:<input type=text ng-model="phoneModel"/>
 Phone Price:<input type=text ng-model="phonePrice"/>
 <input type=button value="Add New Phone" ng-click="addNewPhone()"/>
</body>
</html>
-------------------------------------------
```

When I push element using addNewPhone, the pushing is happening, but the total number of phones is not updated. **Is there any other way to trigger it except assinging $scope.noOfPhones inside addNewPhone function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
<p>Total number of phones: {{phones.length}}</p>
```

noOfPhones is bound to a value (not a reference) and that is why it is not updating.